# If $|\int fg| \le M\|f\|_p$ for all $f\in L^p$, show that $g \in L^{q}$ and $\|g\|_q \le M$, where $1/p +1/q=1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $g$ be an integrable function on $[0,1]$ and let $1 \leq p < \infty$. Suppose there is a constant $M$ such that

$$ \left|\int f \;g \right| \leq M \; \|f\|_p $$
for all bounded measurable functions $f$.

Show that

a) $g \in L^q$ and

b) $||g||_q \leq M$ where $q$ is the conjugate number of $p$ (i.e. $1/p + 1/q =1$ ).

For a), I used Holder's inequality to obtain

\begin{align}\left|\int f \; g \right| &\leq \int |f \; g| \\ &= \|f \; g \|_1 \\ &\leq \|f\|_p \|g\|_q \end{align}

So $g \in L^q$. I am not sure how to bound $\|g\|_q $ by $M$. Is Riesz Representation Theorem used here?

Comment: Unless your measure is finite, that $f$ is bounded does not guarantee that $||f||_p < \infty$.

Comment: isn't $[0,1]$ a finite set?

Comment: You have not specified the measure. It is more clear that you explicitly state that you are working with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Yes that is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use the Riesz representation theorem to solve the problem.
The hypothesis
$$ \left| \int f g \right | \leq M \| f\|_{p}$$
shows in particular that the element $g$ defines a linear continuous functional $T_g$ on the space $L^{p}$ via the relation
$$T_g(f) = \int f g.$$
Now, Riesz representation theorem tells you that there exists a unique $h \in L^{q}$ that represents the functional $T_g$ in the sense that
$$T_g(f) = \int hf \hspace{0.9 cm} \text{for any $f \in L^{p}$.}$$
Moreover, the theorem states that $\|T_g\| = \|h\|_{q}$. From this you may deduce that $g=h$ and since you already have seen that $\|T_g\| \leq M$, you inmediately obtain that $\|g \| \leq M.$

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $g$ is real valued and $p>1$. (The case $p=1$ is similar).

I will prove b) directly and a) follows from b).

Let $N$ be a positive integer and $f=(sgn \,g)|g|^{q/p}I_{|g| \leq N}$ where $q$ is the conjugate index. Then $g$ is bounded and the given inequality becomes $\int_{|g| \leq N} |g|^{q} \leq M (\int_{|g| \leq N} |g|^{q})^{1/p}$. This implies that $(\int_{|g| \leq N} |g|^{q})^{1/q} \leq M$. now let $N \to \infty$.

Comment: actually my part a) is not correct as there is no guarantee that $g \in L^q$ to begin with for the Holder's inequality to hold.

Comment: @user770687 I have proved both parts of the question simultaneously.

Comment: I can follow the reasoning above but I am wondering what is $I_{|g| \leq N}$ and how does letting $N \to \infty $ prove a)? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user770687 $I_A$ is the function defined by $I_A(x)=1$ if $x \in A$ and $0$ if $x \notin A$. For the last step in my argument you have to apply Monotone Convergence Theorem and the fact that the sets $\{x: |g|x)| \leq N\}$ increase to $[0,1]$ as $ N \to \infty$.